# Do I register as baker without fund on public key?

Tags: tezos-client, baker

I have my node up and bootstrapped. I generated key by cmd `sudo -u tezos tezos-client activate account 'ALIAS'`. Now I just created account on terminal that's why seems like there is no need to import account as import account shows me "Account already exist".

I'm trying the command to register with this one `sudo -u tezos tezos-client register key testy12 as delegate` but this shows me error like below.

```
Erroneous command line argument 3 (testy12).
  no public key hash alias named testy12
  cannot read file (Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOENT, "open", "testy12"))
  Failed to read a b58check_encoding data (Signature.Public_key_hash): "testy12"
```

I checked there is file inside the .tezos-client with public key hash already exist. Is that because of 0 fund in pub key?

If I try with the pubkey hash like this `sudo -u tezos tezos-client register key tz1NhTmL9AuetbQrAg3daigDoXcqx7K6ewA9 as delegate` It says `no keys for the source contract tz1NhTmL9AuetbQrAg3daigDoXcqx7K6ewA9`

Answer (score 1):

There was mistake while importing account. Need to perform the below command to import the key first.
`sudo -u tezos tezos-client import secret key testy12 encrypted:YOUR_ENCRYPTEDKEY`

and then need to perform the command `sudo -u tezos tezos-client register key testy12 as delegate`